# What's the meaning of lunch in a bit

Tags: meaning

My friend just told me lunch in a bit, I think that means have lunch for little bit, and I googled the meaning of "lunch in" and "in a bit", but couldn't find the answer, anyone could answer this question? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

*In a bit* is a vague time expression that means "sometime later."

*X in a bit* doesn't refer to the duration of X, but the fact that X will happen at a later time.

You can say "X *for* a bit" to refer to the duration of X similarly.

> I'll be available in a bit. (I will be available sometime later, not an exact or determinate time)
>
> I am available for a bit. (I am currently available for a short amount of  time, not an exact or determinate amount of time)
>
> I'll be available for a bit. (At some point in the future, I will be available for a short, indeterminate amount of time.)

This is similar to "in a while/for a while".

Comment: Worth noting that it's quite informal. You probably wouldn't say this to business contacts that you don't know very well.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "lunch in a bit" is typically an invitation to lunch, the meal typically eaten at midday, in a short time (time denoted with the word "bit"). With the question mark omitted I can understand your confusion.

Comment: as a statement it’s usually interpreted as “I’ll be ready for lunch in a short while.” as a question it’s “would you be ready to go to lunch in a short while?”

Comment: One can't really say that it's an "invitation" without some context.  If the guy says "I'm going to lunch in a bit" it doesn't imply that you're invited.